# Django 1.8 gets installed in Python 2.7 instead of Python 3.4

Tags: software-installation, python, python3

I have two versions of Python installed: 2.7 and 3.4. I installed Django 1.8 as recommended in the Django tutorial. However, it got installed in Python 2.7 instead of Python 3.4 so when I type `import django` in Python 3.4 I get the error message

```
 ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

If I type `import django` in Python 2.7 I get no errors.

Can anybody explain how I get Django 1.8 to be in the Python 3.4 path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install `django` with `pip3`, which is an easy way.

Follow below to install `pip3` and `django`:

1. `sudo apt-get update`. Update your repositories to get the latest application versions available in your repositories.
2. `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`. This will download `pip3`.
3. `sudo pip3 install django`. This will download the latest global django version for python3.
4. `django-admin --version`. Verify what version you got. I got `1.8.3`, which you also should get. You can also verify which version you have like this:
   `python3`

   ```
   import django
   print(django.get_version())
   ```

#### Reference

- [Django FAQ installation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/faq/install/)
- [How To Install the Django Web Framework on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-django-web-framework-on-ubuntu-14-04)